# Animated Notify Icon like the task manager graph

Tags: vb.net, animation, graph, notifyicon

I'm trying to create a bandwidth monitor - I've done most of it, but I want to have a notifyicon that changes dependent on the bandwidth.

The same as when you open task manager and then minimise it, there is a little animated bar graph by the clock showing CPU usage... How do I do that???

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either render all possible images beforehand and then just shop appropriate icon in the tray, or you can draw icons dynamically at runtime.

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2005/09/12/animation-and-text-in-system-tray-using-c.aspx) for more info on second approach.

Comment: Hmmm - this seems a lot more complicated that I was hoping!

I will have a go at this when I get a spare 5 minutes!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

create an icon in memory and change the icon on the notify object?

or get a collection of icons